# ImportError importing class from file in same directory Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have two files

import_1.py

```
class Test:
  pass
```

import_2.py

```
from import_1 import Test
```

Directory structure is:

```
Python_Testing
  import_1
  import_2
```

When I run import_2.py I get the error

```
  File "c:\Users\61403\Desktop\Python_Testing\import_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from import_1 import Test
ImportError: cannot import name 'Test' from 'import_1' (c:\Users\61403\Desktop\Python_Testing\import_1.py)
```

Hovering over the `Test` on VSCode, it knows that it is a class.

Why is this error popping up?
[image]

Comment: Couldn't reproduce problem, I had no trouble importing the class from the first file using the same code you posted. From Google, these import errors often appear to be problems of circular imports, but that shouldn't be a problem if import_1 only includes the two lines of code and no imported modules.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely silly. Auto Save wasn't turned on on my new laptop, so apparently import_1.py wasn't getting saved or sth and so could never be imported.

Comment: Please read [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I think this is not reproducible